# How to make sure something is being unsubscribed in angular 2+

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to understand subscriptions in angular and after some reading I have taken the below approach.

I am using **.pipe(takeUntil())** in order to unsubscribe.

Is this the right way to check if the subscription has successfully unsubscribed

```
// subject I'm using to unsubscribe subscriptions
private onDestroy$ = new Subject();

// The call to load data
this.service.method()
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
    tap(() => console.log('unsubscribed')) // <== does this run when it unsubscribes ?
  )
  .subscribe((pData => {
  });
```

**OnDestroy:**

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.onDestroy$.next(); <== is this necessary ? I'm not sending data
   this.onDestroy$.complete();
}
```

I have aslo read that you do not need to unsubscribe from HTTP requests as it runs the complete() after getting the result and unsubscribes itself, is that correct?

**Can you please explain this next statement to me aswell:**

"Using an operator like takeUntil instead of manually unsubscribing will also complete the observable, triggering any completion event on the observable."

Comment: Here is some explanation about a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092776/angular-7-am-i-creating-too-many-subscriptions/54093438#54093438

Comment: Make sure that `takeUntil` is always the last operation you use in `pipe()`, it creates a mirror of your observable source, and you subscribe on this mirror. When you destroy the component, you complete the mirror, so all subscriptions on this mirror are destroyed.

Comment: Does it have to be last even if the next operator does not use a observable, in this case, it just writes a log ?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Comment: Yes, this link will explain better than I can ! :)